# READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Backward Compatibiolity

Tags: android

I have an app that accesses SD storage read-only and therefore had to add the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in order for it to run on Android 4.4 (the priv was added in Jelly Bean but not enforced until KitKat). This works fine.

The issue is that when installed on an earlier Android version (pre-4.2), it tells the user that it is requesting permission for "Developer Tools: Test access to protected storage". Huh? So far I haven't had any user blow-back (most people never pay attention to that stuff), but I was expecting earlier versions to ignore the new setting altogether.

Is this a known behavior?

Comment: What specific environment are you testing this on? Prior to 4.1, the permission did not exist, and so it should be completely ignored by the device.

Comment: Both devices that I saw this on are running 4.1.1. After further investigation, I think it may only occur when doing a "direct" install as opposed to installing from the Google Play Store. In my testing work, I usually install on devices directly by downloading from Dropbox, so maybe that explains it.

Comment: If you only distribute through the Play Store, that may suffice. Note that if you distribute through other channels, like the Amazon AppStore for Android, that same message may return.